# How to describe “many many of”?

Tags: word-choice

For example:

> There are **____** apps in the App Store.

Should I use *enormous*? Or *massive*? Or any better one for a formal presentation?

Comment: A dictionary is a useful reference. Please do look up *enormous* and *massive* to see the distinction from *numerous*. Also, see *multitude/multitudinous*.

Comment: Amusingly, I read an online article that described a space capsule returning to Earth under *massive parachutes*. Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

A *huge number of* or *a great number of* can be useful expressions:

There is a huge number of apps..

Comment: I think this should be 'there are a huge number of apps' rather than 'there is' because apps are plural. An example where 'is' makes sense would be, 'There is a huge host of soldiers' because the 'is' refers to the host, which is a collective noun, which is then subcategorised as comprising soldiers.

Answer (score 1):

*Numerous* or *various* can work in that sentence as well.

Answer (score 1):

*[Plenty](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/plenty)*: (Pronoun) A large or sufficient amount or quantity; more than enough.

> There are **plenty** of apps in the App store.

*[Copious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/copious)*: (Adjective) Very large in amount or number.

> There are **copious** amounts of apps in the App store.

*[Abundant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Abundant?s=t):* (Adjective) Existing or available in large quantities; plentiful.

> There is an abundance of apps in the App store.

---

However, without any additions to your statement:

> There are ? apps in the App Store.

*[Many](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/many)*: (Determiner) Constituting or forming a large number; numerous: many people.

*[Countless](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/countless)*: (Adjective) Too numerous to count.

*[Innumerable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/innumerable)*: (Adjective) Very numerous.